# Bootstrap Menu On Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the color of the navbar using custom css when link is active but when I click to another page it doesn't apply.

```
    #custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 1);
}
#custom-navbar.navbar-default {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    background-color: rgba(47, 46, 46, 1);
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(47, 46, 46, 1);

}

#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-navbar .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active> a,
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav .parent>li>a:focus{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);

}

#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #2f2e2e;
}
```

I'm also posting the website I've created if you like to have a view and have a better idea.
[Website link](http://79.170.40.178/studimestudime.com/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:active{
    background-color: #056B28;
}
```

Comment: The `!important` suffix isn't needed and should always be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are not specific enough. This:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Is overridden by this:

```
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(47, 46, 46, 1);
}
```

If you use an ID selector in a base statement, you need to also use an ID selector in an override.

```
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, 
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, 
#custom-navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Tried that but three elements are one the homepage and when it is loaded it set active all of them. I want to be active only the one which is clicked.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Only one element should be active. Apparently you have bigger issues.

Comment: As I using wordpress the menu is integrated from it, so when i'm the archive page and than click to one of other elements of the navbar I must have a fully specified address for that element. That's what causes all of elements to be active. Any idea how should i change it?

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments.